# Parse Push Notification - PHP API

Tags: php, parse-platform, push-notification, push, eol

Parse Push Notifications are working. The thing is that I am trying to send a multiline notification and the PHP API is not detecting my EOL command. The messages arrived exactly as I send them:

> Line1\r\nLine2

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

EDIT

This is my code:

```
require 'autoload.php';

$app_id = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
$rest_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$master_key = "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";

\Parse\ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );
use Parse\ParsePush;
$data = array("alert" => $_POST["txtMessage"]);
ParsePush::send(array("channels" => ["Test"], "data" => $data));
```

EDIT #2:

My data array:

```
array(1) (
  [alert] => (string) Line1\r\nLine2
)
```

Comment: Please add source code responsible for sending and preparing the message.

Comment: @awons I added the code to the question...

Comment: Please also dump your $data array. Would be good to see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are escaping your string somewhere along the way.

This is how the escaped string will look like in PHP:

```
var_dump("Line1\\r\\nLine2");

string(14) "Line1\r\nLine2"
```

Simply because you escaped the escape character.

What you need is this:

```
var_dump("Line1\r\nLine2");

string(12) "Line1
Line2"
```

The above code should produce what you need. Check other parts of your code (also the frontend part) if there is anything that is escaping the string.